# How to display data stored in sessions in mvc c#

Tags: c#, session, model-view-controller

I'm storing list of string in to a session. Then I don't know how to get those data to display in my view.

This is my code:

```
public List<Details> d = new List<Details>();

[HttpPost]
public void getDatas(string destination)
{
     XElement rootele = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/CruiseData/cruiseprodutstwo.xml"));
     var getneededData = rootele.Elements("CruiseProduct")
                                .Where(l => l.Element("Location").Value == destination)
                                .Select(s => s.Element("Name").Value);

     foreach (var itm in getneededData)
     {
         d.Add(new Details
         {
             cruiseName = itm
         });    
     } 

     Session["names"] = d;     
     Response.Redirect("Check",true);   
}
```

This is my check action method

```
public ActionResult Check()            
{
     var chk = Session["names"];    
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Is the `Session["names"]` returning anything in your `Check` method?

Comment: no it does not return anything, but after this getDatas() method finish, I want to display the chek view.

Comment: Is your `getneededData` object populated? To redirect to the `Check` view you can use `return RedirectToAction("Check");`

Comment: yes (getneededData count is 2 and finally d count is also 2), if I use RedirectToAction("check") then it does not go through "check"

Comment: it's working. but  my secondview("Check") is not display. but if I enter the url in the address bar then display. in here, *from my first view I'm passing selected value to getDatas method. *then do some query in the method and then want to display that data[session] in the second view("check"). how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your data in ViewBag, then retrieve them in view:

```
public ActionResult Check()
{
 ViewBag.SessionData = Session["names"] as List<DetailsList>;

 Return View();
}
```

Then in your view, use simply as

```
@If (ViewBag["SessionData"]!= null){
// Do jobs with SessionDetails what you want
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works. but now my secondview("Check") is not display. but if I enter the url in the address bar then display.
in herer,
*from my first view I'm passing selected value to getDatas method.
*then do some query in the method and then want to display that data[session] in the second view("check"). how can I do that

Comment: Please paste your code for secondview("check") as well, then I can check it for you, what do you enter in the URL?

Comment: Replace "Response.Redirect("Check",true);" with  "return RedirectToAction("Check");"

Answer (score 0):

> Controller

```
public ActionResult Check()

    {
        var chk = Session["names"];
        List<Details> list = Session["names"] as List<Details>;
        ViewBag.MyList = list ;
        return View();

    }
```

> View

```
@ViewBag.MyList

// e.g.
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is better to use `ViewBag`, `ViewData` and/or `TempData` when playing with MVC.

The use is quite simple for all the three. Here are the steps :

1. You assign them some value/object : `ViewBag.SomeField = SomeValue;`
2. You use them on your view side : `@ViewBag.SomeField.`

Here are some link that will definitely get you through :

- [ViewBag ViewData and TempData](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option)
- [ViewBag ViewData and TempData Basics](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12427/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-in-mvc.aspx)

Since you are redirecting to an action method here, I would suggest using `TempData` for your case and using that in the view.

Hope this helps.